# Redhat php-apd installation

Tags: php, linux, redhat

I'm recently trying to profile my Facebook app with php-apd profiler, but i don't have any experience with redhat dest.
how to install **php-apd profiler** under redhat? what is the exact command?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply using: `pecl install apd`

Since it's a PECL extension, in theory that command should be enough to install it. If that doesn't work, you may be able to find more information on [the PHP manual page about installing PECL extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php).

Answer (score 0):

Think you should go through the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) once.